# Unable to connect zaiper with Botium box

Tags: slack-api, zapier, botium-box

I am trying to connect Botium-box with Zapier , with intention to connect Slack bot.

1. While trying to connect to Botium-box from Zapier, I am getting following error (even after providing recently generated API Key:

   authentication failed: The API Key you supplied is invalid: Not logged in
   [image]
2. On Botium-box, where could I find a out of box way to connect to Slack?
   Since under chatbots options unable to find Slack bot option.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. What Botium Box flavour are you using ? For Botium Box Mini, there is only very limited API integration possible.
2. There is no native support for Slack bots in Botium.

Comment: Hi,1) I am evaluating Botium-box using hosted Botuim box. Ref: https://www.botium.ai/getting-started/.  2) And this link mentions that we're able to connect Botium Box to slack. https://zapier.com/apps/botium-box/integrations/slack

Comment: Yes, that's the Botium Box Mini - it only has very limited API integration.